# How to arrange 4 JPG files (plots) in four quarters of one full page?

Tags: graphics, floats

I have four figures marked as Plot1.jpg, Plot2.jpg, Plot3.jpg and Plot4.jpg. I like to divide one full page into four quarters of equal length and place one plot in each quarter and also allow some space for caption of these 4 subfigures. Kindly let me know how to do it! Thanks a lot for great help!

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=8cm]{example-image-a}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=8cm]{example-image-b}
            \caption{B}
        \end{subfigure}\\
        \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=8cm]{example-image-c}
            \caption{C}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=8cm]{example-image-duck}
            \caption{Duck}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Caption for all 4 subfigures}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```